# Generics mismatched types

Tags: rust

Why can this code not compile? Shouldn't I be able to pass `&str` as parameter here?

```
struct S<T: AsRef<str>>{
    t: T
}

fn bar<T: AsRef<str>>(t: T) -> S<T>{
    S{t}
}

fn foo<T: AsRef<str>>(t: T) -> S<T> {
    bar("b")
}

fn main() {
    foo("a");
}
```

Error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:10:9
   |
9  | fn foo<T: AsRef<str>>(t: T) -> S<T> {
   |        - this type parameter
10 |     bar("b")
   |     --- ^^^ expected type parameter `T`, found `&str`
   |     |
   |     arguments to this function are incorrect
   |
   = note: expected type parameter `T`
                   found reference `&'static str`
help: the return type of this call is `&'static str` due to the type of the argument passed
  --> src/main.rs:10:5
   |
10 |     bar("b")
   |     ^^^^---^
   |         |
   |         this argument influences the return type of `bar`
note: function defined here
  --> src/main.rs:5:4
   |
5  | fn bar<T: AsRef<str>>(t: T) -> S<T>{
   |    ^^^                ----
```

Comment: What happens if you call bar(t) instead of bar("b")?

Comment: this works. But I want to understand why the code like this doesn't work.

Comment: I think when compiler parses signature of `foo`, it doesn't consider how you called `foo` anywhere else in the program. E.g. remove `foo("a");` and the error is the same. Thus the compiler expects the return type be derived from `T`, which is provided by input argument. But since you you hardcoded `bar("b")` the return type is always this one type `S<&str>`, which would violate the signature of `foo` if `T` would be any other type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rust requires that generics typecheck correctly without having concrete types plugged in. (This is unlike C++.)

Look at `foo` in detail but rename its generic parameter to avoid confusion:

```
fn foo<U: AsRef<str>>(t: U) -> S<U> {
    bar("b")
}
```

You call `bar("b")` and return its result. `bar("b")` monomorphizes to `bar::<&'static str>("b")`, which returns `S<&static str>`, independently of what `U` is.

This is not correct, because you have no guarantee that `foo` needs to return a `S<&static str>`, because you don't control its generic argument.

For example, if I were to call `foo("a".to_string())`, it would monomorphize as `foo::<String>`, which is expected to return a `S<String>` - and yet your implementation still tries to return a `S<&'static str>`.

That's why the compiler rejects your code beforehand.

The error message is unfortunately a bit misleading. You see, Rust deduces types both from arguments and also result usage.

Because you return the result of `bar` from `foo`, the compiler deduces that `bar` needs to return `S<U>`, and therefore `bar` also needs to take a `U` as the argument, but you're passing a `&'static str`, which may or may not be the same as `U`. And so you get the type mismatch reported on the argument instead of the result.